# Data Type validation in textbox

Tags: vb.net, validation

Trying to make a validation where only letters can be entered into a textbox. I've got that part working, but I would also like the ability for the user to use the backspace button, and I'm not sure how

```
Private Sub TxtBoxCustForename_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtBoxCustForename.KeyPress
   If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 65 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 122 Then 'Ensures only letters can be entered by using the ASCII converter'
      e.Handled = True
      MessageBox.Show("You may only input letters")
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Chr(91) is "[", so you might want to adjust the range to exclude 91-96.

Comment: `If Not Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) AndAlso Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then`  Also make sure the TextBox doesn't have a ContextMenu to avoid pasting unwanting elements.  This would be better handled in the Validation events.

Answer (score 1):

Input validation is a built-in feature of `.NET`. You don't need to capture key presses and manually code your own solution.

You might want to use a `MaskedTextBox` as suggested in this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/user-input-validation-in-windows-forms

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `If` statement like this:

```
If (Asc(e.KeyChar) < 65 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 122) And Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
```

Ascii 8 is the Backspace key.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the KeyPress event, use the [TextChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged?view=netframework-4.8) event.  Also, I would recommend using the [IsNumeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnumeric-function) function to test whether it is a number or not.

```
Private Sub TxtBoxCustForename_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtBoxCustForename.TextChanged
   For Each entry as Char in TxtBoxCustForename.Text
       If IsNumeric(entry) Then
          MessageBox.Show("You may only input letters")
          Exit For
       End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis.  It also doesn't stop the user from imputing that unwanted character.

Comment: They're not asking to stop the user from entering a number, just to show a message when they do.

Comment: The `e.Handled = True` stops the key press from proceeding in their code, So yes, the intention is to stop it.

Comment: No one should be using `IsNumeric` under any circumstances but certainly not in this case. If you want to know whether a `Char` value is a digit then you use `Char.IsDigit`. That said, the logic here should not be whether the character is a digit but whether it is not a letter. Good thing there's a `Char.IsLetter` method too. You certainly shouldn't be testing every character on every key press either. The whole point of handling the `KeyPress` event is to validate that key press.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use .NET then use .NET.

```
Private Sub TxtBoxCustForename_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtBoxCustForename.KeyPress
    Dim keyChar = e.KeyChar

    If Not Char.IsLetter(keyChar) AndAlso Not Char.IsControl(keyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True

        MessageBox.Show("You may only input letters")
    End If
End Sub
```

This still doesn;t prevent the user pasting invalid text into the control though, so you still need to handle the `Validating` event or use a custom control that catches paste operations.